# Service m8 forms populated with wordpress form information

Tags: servicem8

is there a way of us using standard contact forms on our wordpress sites and using servicem8 API system can the forms within service m8 be automatically be populated with the information from a wordpress contact form

contact form in wordpress (preferablby jetforumbuilder contact form) to populate the service m8 form in the background